How to add command `noise_model = get_noise ( 0.05,0.05 )` to my simulator in qiskit
I'm using qiskit online, and want to run my simulator with the following command:
noise_model = get_noise ( 0.05,0.05 )
However, where previously I could insert lines of code to affect my circuit, I now only see the "setup and run" option. How can I add my command?

I think you want the "code editor" panel. You can turn on the "code editor" panel by going to "View -> Panels -> Code Editor". After you turn on the "code editor" in qiskit Quantum Lab, you will see a panel on left (by default).
Now, in this panel from the top you can select if you want the code to be displayed in OpenQASM2.0 or Qiskit. You can edit the OpenQASM2.0 code in the code editor but you won't be able to edit the qiskit code directly in the code editor (qiskit code will be read-only). I'm guessing this is because converting an assembly language like OpenQASM to Python is relatively easy, you will notice the Qiskit code generated by the composer uses a very specific and consistent way for naming the registers. However doing the conversion in the other way, is not that easy due to the different ways of writing python codes.
But if you want you can always export the generated circuit to a python file (Use the "3-dot" menu on the code editor panel) and then add your noise_model to it and simulate it. Alternatively, you can refer to this link which shows how you can use a Circuit Composer widget from a jupyter notebook.
